# CorePlot chart not showing up in PDF made with -dataWithPDFInsideRect

Tags: macos, pdf, core-plot, nsimage, nsimageview

I'm generating a PDF from a view using `-dataWithPDFInsideRect:`.

Within the view is a `CPTXYGraph` which displays wonderfully in a Window but doesn't show up in the PDF at all.

I also tried putting an NSImageView into my view, then generating an NSImage from my core plot chart and putting that NSImage into the NSImageView.. but the NSImage is just empty white.

How can I either:

a) Include a Core Plot chart in my View such that it will be shown in the PDF generated by `-dataWithPDFInsideRect:`, or..

b) generate a proper NSImage from my Core Plot chart so that I can put it into the NSImageView whic will then show up in the PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the graph is the only thing displayed in your view, get the PDF data from it directly using the `-dataForPDFRepresentationOfLayer` method. This will give you a PDF that preserves text and lines as objects so that it will scale smoothly. Otherwise, use the `-imageOfLayer` method to retrieve an `NSImage` of the graph layer.

Comment: The graph is part of a larger view and I want to be able to generate the entire page as a vector PDF. I would LOVE to have the chart as a vector instead of a raster image. For some reason the `-imageOfLayer` didn't work for me at first. It did this time though, not sure what is different. It doesn't look great, because it's a raster image. How do I take the pdf data from the layer and embed it into a larger pdf page/document? :/

Comment: "How do I take the pdf data from the layer and embed it into a larger pdf page/document?" Open a new question for that here on StackOverflow.